# Where can I find php_svn.dll

Tags: php, svn, php-extension

I recently upgraded to PHP 5.3.5 for windows. I have used the subversion extension on previous versions, but php_svn.dll is not included in the 5.3.5 version. I tried to copy the dll from the previous installation of php, but I get this message when trying to start php.

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: svn: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626

I have search for a download site for php_svn.dll but to no avail.